# Don't understand why there's an extra window

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

So, I've two tkinter stuffs, one using `class` and the another one without class. Everything should work the same, but when I use "classes", it creates two windows, the one that I actually created and the one I don't know where it came from (probably because I'm using both the `Frame` and `tk.Tk`, but it doesn't work that way without classes).

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
framer = tk.Frame(window)
window.title("Test")
window.geometry("720x480+360+240")
window.mainloop()
```

Above is the one without classes.
The one below is the one with classes.

```
try:
        import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: #2.x
        import Tkinter as tk


class typtolator(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                window = tk.Tk()
                framer = tk.Frame(window)
                window.title("Typtolator")
                window.geometry("720x480+360+240")



app = typtolator()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bryan Oakley points out in his answer, the problem is your class *is* a `tk.Tk` since it's derived from one, so the extra window is because it creates a second instance of plain `tk.Tk` in its `__init__()` method.

What's he left out was an example of doing it properly—which I think may be  important—so that's shown below:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: #2.x
    import Tkinter as tk


class Typtolator(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Call superclass' __init__().
        framer = tk.Frame(self)
        self.title("Typtolator")
        self.geometry("720x480+360+240")


app = Typtolator()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You get two windows because you create two windows.

The first window is `app`, an instance of `typtolator`. This class is a subclass of `tk.Tk` and thus *is a* `tk.Tk`. '

The second window is `window` which is an instance of `tk.Tk` that you create when you create `app`.

The solution is to one or the other: subclass `tk.Tk`, or don't create a subclass and then explicitly create an instance of `tk.Tk`.